# installing python library from github

Tags: python, github

Hi I am trying to install this python library from github:

https://github.com/eskerda/PyBikes

However when I typed:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/eskerda/PyBikes.git
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/eskerda/PyBikes.git
```

It returns:

```
Cannot find command 'git'
```

This is my first time trying to install a library from github, so maybe I am missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you installed `git` in your system and it's in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git):

> pip currently supports cloning over **git**, **git+https** and **git+ssh**:
>
> ```
>  Here are the supported forms:
>  git+git://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject 
>  git+https://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
>  git+ssh://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
>  git+git@git.myproject.org:MyProject#egg=MyProject
> ```